# Change gif animation based on Windows Application Theme

Tags: wpf, animation, themes

I have a two gif images for Dark and Light theme respectively. I am trying to use them in a sample WPF application. The goal is based on Windows Theme change from settings, the gif image will also change. I am using XamlAnimatedGif for gif animation. So, my code for gif image with animation looks like this,

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns:gif="https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif">

<Image
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    MaxWidth="20"
                    MaxHeight="20"
                    gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="{DynamicResource SampleAnimation}" />
```

And in Assets/Animations folder I have created two new folders, Light and Dark where the gif animation for respective theme is stored and created Two resource dictionary called Light.xaml and Dark.xaml.

In these resource dictionary file, the key is written like this,

```
<Style x:Key="SampleAnimation" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri" Value="/Assets/Animations/Light/sample_animation.gif"/>
    </Style>
```

**But the problem is the animation is not showing at all. How to solve this problem?**

Comment: You are trying to assign a Style resource to the SourceUri property. That won't work. You may write `Style="{DynamicResource SampleAnimation}"`.